# Create multiple nested child in parent

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a trouble to create a nested object via EF.

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public ICollection<B>? CollectionOfB { get; set; }
}
public class B 
{ 
    [Key] 
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public virtual B? ParentB { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<b>? ChildB { get; set; }
    public long IdOfA { get; set; }
    public A ParentA {get; set;}
}
```

and I'm trying to insert a complex entity into the db with EF

like

```
{
    "title: "1",
    "collectionOfB": [
        {
            "title":"sub1",
            "childB": [
                "title": "sub-sub-1"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But have an error

insert or update on table "BTable" violates foreign key constraint "FK_BTable_IdOfA"

DETAIL: Key (IdOfA)=(0) is not present in table "ATable"

Comment: The crucial part (the part about how you make your inserts) is missing. Normally EF allows graph inserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was because of a mistake in model generation.

If someone reads this, be sure that you put your main entity to child as reference.

In initialization part, you don't have an Id of parent entity, but you already have your entity instance. So just add that to your child as reference like this:

```
new B 
{
    ...
    ParentA = YourA;
}
```